# How can I get a message to appear only once if a random number doesn't equal one in a vector?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, vector, foreach

I am making a small lottery game. Everything works fine but I can't get the message I want to be displayed if the user doesn't guess the correct number to only appear once. I don't know how to get it to appear only once and I know why it appears multiple times.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] userGuessNums = new int[10];
        Console.WriteLine("Input 10 numbers between 1-50.");
        for (int i = 0; i < userGuessNums.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
                string numbers = Console.ReadLine();
                int userNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(numbers);
                userGuessNums[i] = userNumbers;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
            }
        }
        Console.Clear();
        Random randomer = new Random();
        int randomNumber = randomer.Next(1, 51);

        Console.WriteLine("The numbers you have chosen:");

        foreach (int element in userGuessNums)
        {
            Console.Write(element + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to see if you have won.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The winning number is: " + randomNumber);

        for (int i = 0; i < userGuessNums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (userGuessNums[i] == randomNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You won!");
            else if (userGuessNums[i] != randomNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you lose.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So do you want it to loop through all given numbers and only display if ALL of them are losing numbers? Some clarification on your win condition would be helpful.

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Modify your last for loop like so. Loop through your array and find a winning number then set your win prompt outside the loop.

Why does this work? Let's break it down. Mainly I'm separating the prompt for the win from the loop; this is going to stop it from continually displaying, which is what you want. However, we still need to isolate the element within the array that is an acceptable condition. By setting our `userWonNum` outside of the for loop with a value of `-1` (An impossible win condition), it protects from an accidental win. Then we loop through our array and find a winning number and assign it to that variable. Once the loop is completed, then it will move to the next block and check if we had one.

Exciting tip on this. If you loop through with more than one winning number, it will re-assign multiple times if you implement more than one winning number, but for now, it will work.

```
        int userWonNumber = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < userGuessNums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (userGuessNums[i] == randomNumber)
            {
                userWonNumber = randomNumber;
            }
        }

        if (userWonNumber == randomNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Congrats, you won!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you lost!");
        }
```

Comment: Would it not be a better solution to create a boolean variable and set it to true if the guessed number matches the random number? This way you don't have to worry about comparing a magic number to the random number after the loop.

Comment: Yes that is valid but this way he can extrapolate his win number and remove a line or two of code during refactor. `Console.WriteLine($"Congrats your number {userWonNumber} won!")`

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the random number is in the array input by the user.

Import Linq at the top of your code

```
using System.Linq;
```

And after `Console.WriteLine("The winning number is: " + randomNumber);` replace the for-loop with

```
if (userGuessNums.Contains(randomNumber))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You won!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you lose.");
}
```

Comment: This is a valid solution but he may be a student so it may be best to stay away from Linq, since he may not know exactly what is happening.